# TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable Tensorflow estimator.py DNNClassifier

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, classification

Currently I am working on a DNNClassifier to predict stock trends for next day.

Below is the code for DNNClassifier created using tensorflow:

```
feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column(k) for k in FEATURES]

classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                                hidden_units=[250, 200, 150, 100, 50],
                                                n_classes=5,
                                                model_dir="/stock_model")

def input_fn(data_set):
    feature_cols = {k: tf.constant(data_set[k].values) for k in FEATURES}
    labels = tf.constant(data_set[LABEL].values)
    #print (feature_cols)
    return feature_cols, labels
estimator = tf.contrib.learn.Estimator(model_fn=classifier)
estimator.fit(input_fn=lambda:input_fn(training_set), steps=5000)
```

When executed the code throws below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/phani/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/phani/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "/home/phani/TensorFlow/pythoncodefordnnclassifier/iris_Classification.py", line 45, in <module>
    estimator = tf.contrib.learn.Estimator(model_fn=classifier)
  File "/home/phani/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 990, in __init__
    if params is None or 'params' in model_fn_args:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Could you please help me in solving this. If this is an existing issue, a link to that would be of great help.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having this same problem, did you ever figure this out?